# How can I filter out values in a vector that are less than n indexes from the preceding nonzero value?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a vector of doubles, which I have thresholded as follows:

```
v = rand(1, 100);
thresh = v > .5;
```

The `thresh` variable now contains boolean values.  I would like to filter out all `true` values that follow another `true` value by strictly less than *n* indexes.  Let's set *n* to `3` for the purpose of this question.  Thus, given a segment of `v` `[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1]`, I would like to filter it so as to obtain `[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ]`.

This can be done trivially in a loop, but my `v` variable is quite long, so I'm wondering whether or not a vectorized solution is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the ways to do this are variants on the same trick.
First construct the vector of all the 1's you might keep.  Then 'andnot' it with the original vector.

In your example that mask vector would be
[0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]

To get this vector there are a couple different ways.  One is with a sparse matrix multiply.  You can construct the sparse matrix you want with spdiags

```
tlen = length(thresh);
d = spdiags(ones(tlen, n-1),1:(n-1),tlen,tlen);
mask = thresh * d;
```

Then 'andnot' with the mask

```
thresh = thresh & ~mask;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ind = bsxfun(@plus, find(thresh(1:end-n+1)), (1:n-1).');
thresh(unique(ind(:))) = 0;
```